# nHibernate fails with whereNot restriction but not with where restriction

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm currently working on a C# project where we use NHibernate.
In the project we have a table called "Auftrag" where I only need some columns.

To select only the columns I need I use this code:

```
ProjectionList projectionListSubTypeAuftrag = Projections.ProjectionList();
projectionListSubTypeAuftrag
    .Add(Projections.Property("AuftragID"), "Id")
    .Add(Projections.Property("Status"), "Status")
    .Add(Projections.Property("Typ"), "Typ");

DetachedCriteria auftragCriteria = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(Auftrag));

auftragCriteria.SetProjection(projectionListSubTypeAuftrag);
auftragCriteria.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(SubTypeAuftrag)));

IList<SubTypeAuftrag> auftragSubview;

using (ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    auftragSubview = auftragCriteria.GetExecutableCriteria(session).List<SubTypeAuftrag>();

    tx.Commit();
}
```

This works fine and returns all rows in the table. Now I want to filter with the condition: `Status != 'A'`.

I tried to achive this with the following line

```
auftragCriteria.Add(Restrictions.Not(Restrictions.Eq("Status", 'A')));
```

If I run the code now I get an exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Creating or altering table
>   'FakeWorkTable' failed because the minimum row size would be 16017,
>   including 4 bytes of internal overhead. This exceeds the maximum
>   allowable table row size of 8094 bytes.

When I look at the generated SQL statement everything looks normal, I also can run it in the Microsoft SSMS.

Now the part I do not understand is, when I change the `auftragCriteria.Add(Restrictions.Not(Restrictions.Eq("Status", 'A')));` to `auftragCriteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Status", 'A'));` everything works fine.

What am I missing?

I found a work around:

```
auftragCriteria.Add(Expression.Sql("Status <> 'A'"));
```

works.

If I use `auftragCriteria.Add(Restrictions.Not(Restrictions.Eq("Status", 'A')));`, I get this sql query

```
SELECT this_.auftragid as y0_,
       this_.status    as y1_,
       this_.typ       as y2_
FROM   auftrag this_
WHERE  not (this_.status = 'A' /* @p0 */)
```

And if I use `auftragCriteria.Add(Expression.Sql("Status <> 'A'"));`, I get this:

```
SELECT this_.auftragid as y0_,
       this_.status    as y1_,
       this_.typ       as y2_
FROM   auftrag this_
WHERE  Status <> 'A'
```

Shouldn't they behave the same?

Comment: Does the query with `WHERE  not (this_.status = 'A' /* @p0 */)` actually execute correctly in SSMS?

Comment: @LeffeBrune yes it works in the SSMS

Comment: The error message does not make a lot of sense. Do you do more things inside of your transaction?

Comment: @LeffeBrune Yes I know the message does not make sense :( But I do not make any other requests in the transaction. I also do not under stand why it should be different for `not (this_.status = 'A')` and `WHERE  Status <> 'A'`

Comment: This query is the last I see in the nHibernate Profiler. After the query only errors show up.

Comment: That seems to be related to NHIbernate bug with setting parameter size: https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/issues/1300. Version of NHibernate? How Status property is mapped?

Comment: We use version v5.1.6

Comment: okay thanks I'll check it out

Comment: @RomanArtiukhin I updated to 5.2.7 but I still get the same error.

Comment: How `Status` is mapped? If it's `EnumCharType` - it's still not fixed. See https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/issues/1300#issuecomment-475758336

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from looking at NHibernate source code goes, using `Restrictions.Not(Restrictions.Eq("Status", 'A'))` seems to be the correct way to implement 'not equals' operator. In Java version of Hibernate there is `Restrictions.ne` that is converted to '<>' operator.

Few things I would check. Run your code with the latest NHibernate version and see if the problem persists. Judging by the error message I suspect there is more happening in your code that you've shown here. Try replicating the problem with the least amount of code you possibly can.

Another workaround, which I would argue is better than using `Expression.Sql`, is to use `Lt` and `Gt` with `Or`:

```
auftragCriteria.Add(
    Restrictions.Or(
        Restrictions.Lt("Status", 'A'), 
        Restrictions.Gt("Status", 'A')));
```

Which should become:

```
WHERE (this_.status < 'A' or this.status > 'A')
```

PS: I wrote a little example using NHibernate 5.1.6 and Restrictions.Not works as one would expect. I do not believe your issue has anything to do with NHibernate version.

Comment: We have version 5.1.6 which seems not to have this.

Comment: can you try !Restrictions.Eq(...)